# Erratic light on laptop power adapter

Tags: laptop-repair

I replaced a power board on a Dell Inspiron laptop. If I plug the power adapter into the power board by itself, the light on the adapter stays on, if I connect the power board to the motherboard then plug the power adapter into the power board the light on the adapter goes out. I have pulled everything off the motherboard (hard drive, RAM, CMOS, processor, fan) but still the light goes out if that power board is connected.

Any ideas as to what may be going on?

Comment: Could be that the charger is bad. Do you have access to a different one to test?